# error when importing large database into mysqlAdmin via cmd

Tags: mysql

I get the following error when importing large database into mysqlAdmin via command line.

i am using wamp. i first logged into mysql via my CMD using administrator privileges.

i then logged into mysql with following commands:

```
mysql -h localhost -u john -p
```

i thereafter tried to upload the database with following commands:

```
mysql> mysql -h localhost -u john -p magento < C:\Users\john\Desktop\sql\backup.sql
```

this is the error i got:

```
ERROR:
Unknown command '\U'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\e'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\D'.
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Win32 (AMD64)

Connection id:          55
Current database:
Current user:           john@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 13 hours 22 min 26 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 815  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 888  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 327  Queries per second avg: 0.016
--------------

ERROR:
Unknown command '\l'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont login twice,just run

```
mysql -h localhost -u john -p magento < C:\Users\john\Desktop\sql\backup.sql
```